# How can I represent the numbers for the 3D matrix 512 * 512 * 80 double DICOM?

Tags: matlab, workspace

on the workspace in Matlab gives me an error message:
Cannot display summaries of variables with more than 524288 elements.

I have an idea whether the array could be reduced to the workspace?
I thank you guys for the answer. :)

Comment: Could you post the code that produces this error? (I tried to think of situations that could lead to this message, but I guess I got nowhere.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error.

Why would you want to try to see 20971520 numbers? You can't possibly make sense of that amount of numbers displayed in the screen, and it would take plenty of time and memory (more than the data itself) to load them up and show them to you, and therefore MATLAB decides that what you are trying to do makes no sense and does not allow you to do it.

If you want to see something like that, you will want to either plot it as an image, or just display a subset of its values.

Say you want to plot it and you have this array `data` of the size you said. You could just:

```
imshow(data(:,:,1),[])
```

With 3 lines more you can make a loop that shows all 80 of your slices/projections. Seeing your other questions I see that you want to see the values of the pixels. Just use the [figure datatip](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/interactively-explore-plotted-data.html) to inspect the pixel values, MATLAB allows that.

Instead say you want to inspect some of the values of the array. You could:

```
data(1:10,1:10,1)
```

and this will show you a small subset of the values on the screen. When working with data this big, its impossible to inspect everything, so often you need to query the data with general assesments, rather than pixel-by-pixel ones. For example, if you are worried that your data has zero values, you can do

```
sum(data==0) %returns the number of zeroes
```

or to see if there are NaNs

```
any(isnan(data)) % retuns if there is any NaN value in the data
```

Working with large data (most medical images are) is hard.

Instead, if you really want to see 20971520 numbers because you think you can make sense of them, please contact a university psychology research department, as you must have the most powerful brain in the world! :)

Comment: That's funny, does your MATLAB also refuse to print out inordinately large arrays? Mine happily runs stuff like `ones(1,2^30),` (at the cost of most of my available RAM and several tens of minutes). But I always use `matlab -nodesktop`, so that may be the reason...

Comment: This link may also be relevant: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html

Comment: @Vicky: you can display them at the command prompt, but OP is using the “workspace browser”, which is a GUI around `whos` that also can show individual matrices as a spreadsheet. I think. I always have it off to save screen real estate. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ah I see, I've seen this spreadsheet-like interface before! Thanks for the explanation!